# Prism EventAggregator difference between PubSubEvent<TPayload> Class and CompositePresentationEvent<TPayload> Class

Tags: c#, event-handling, prism, eventaggregator

Im trying to get my EventAggregator in Prism working based on this example [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921173%28v=pandp.40%29).

After having some problems that where caused by mixing up class references i would like to know the difference of:

PubSubEvent Class [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn736103%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx)

and

CompositePresentationEvent Class [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff654534.aspx)

I couldnt find a more detailed information. And both references say **Defines a class that manages publication and subscription to events**.

So far so good. 
But when to use them or which of them?
What is the difference?

Maybe somebody can help me on this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`PubSubEvent` is a newer class replacing `CompositePresentationEvent` which was deprecated.

> The classes in the Events namespace were made obsolete but still exist in Prism 5.0. You should use the classes from the Prism.PubSubEvents portable class library with the Prism.PubSubEvents namespace. The PubSubEvent class replaces the CompositePresentationEvent class.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921144(v=pandp.40).aspx

Comment: Thx, i think this one of the only chapters that i didnt read on this page.